# Extending the User model in Apache Superset

Tags: python, flask, oauth, apache-superset

I want to add some custom attributes to the user model that exist in the user-info of the keycloak user i log in with.
In the superset_config.py i added this:

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models import User
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer

class CustomUser(User):
    __tablename__ = "ab_user"
    custom_attribute = Column(Integer)
```

and this is my CustomSsoSecurityManager class:

```
class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authoauthview = CustomSsoAuthOAuthView

def oauth_user_info(self, provider, res=None):
    logging.debug("Oauth2 provider: {0}.".format(provider))
    if provider == 'keycloak':
        try:
            # Assuming self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider] is correctly set up
            response = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get('userinfo')

            if response.status_code == 200:
                data = response.json()
                username = data.get("preferred_username", "")
                first_name = data.get("given_name", "")
                last_name = data.get("family_name", "")
                email = data.get("email", "")
                customAttribute= data.get("customAttribute", 0)

                user_info = {
                    "username": username,
                    "first_name": first_name,
                    "last_name": last_name,
                    "email": email,
                    "is_active": True,
                    "custom_attribute": customAttribute
                }

                print("User Information:", user_info)

                return user_info
            else:
                logging.debug(f"OAuth provider returned an error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
                return None
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            logging.debug(f"Request to OAuth provider failed: {e}")
            return None
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            logging.debug(f"Error decoding JSON response: {e}")
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            logging.debug(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            return None
```

When the superset database tables are created, i can see the custom_attribute column in the schema,
the problem is when i first login with a keycloak user that has a customAttribute value, nothing is saved in the superset database.
What can i do to make sure the value is saved ?

Also i would like to ask if its possible to make a custom Jinja macro to pass this customAttribute as a parameter in Sql Lab